# como mostrar el resultado de execvp en cliente

Tags: c

tengo masomenos este codigo en mi programa servidor:
if(!fork())
{
    dup2(sockClie,0);//stdin
    dup2(sockclie,1);//stdout
    close(sockClie);
    execvp(arg,arg);
}

lo que quiero es que el servidor me pida los comandos a mi programa clilenet y despues muestre el resultado en cliente. Mi programa servidor funciona con telnet perfectamente pero no asi con mi programa cliente.
como tendria que mejorar mi programa cliente ? gracias

---

```
while(1)
{
    tam_cliente=sizeof cliente;
    sock_cliente=accept(sock_servidor,(struct sockaddr *)&cliente,&tam_cliente);
    if(sock_cliente<0)
    {
        perror("acceptando cliente");
        return -1;
    }

    ip_cliente=inet_ntoa(cliente.sin_addr);
    puerto_cliente=ntohs(cliente.sin_port);
    printf("cliente conectado:%s:%d\n",ip_cliente,puerto_cliente);
    memset(mensaje_cliente,0,sizeof mensaje_cliente);
    //read(sock_cliente,&mensaje_cliente,sizeof mensaje_cliente);
    //printf("mensaje cliente:%s\n",mensaje_cliente);
    if(!fork())
    {
        printf("inicio fork\n");
        close(sock_servidor);
        dup2(sock_cliente,0);
        dup2(sock_cliente,1);
        close(sock_cliente);
        printf("introdusca comando:\n");
        fgets(mensaje_cliente,20,stdin);
        printf("mensaje_cliente=\n%s",mensaje_cliente);
        char *com[]={"ls","-l",NULL};
                    execvp(com[0],com);
        exit(1);
    }
    close(sock_cliente);
}
```

funciona bien con telnet pero no funciona con el programa cliene cualquiera q hice q solo se conecta y q supuestamente como se esta hacieno dup2 con stdin y stdout repito me funciona bien con telnet

Comment: Bienvenido para que podamos entender mejor la pregunta edita la pregunta y muestra el codigo del cliente

Comment: Mejorar un codigo desconocido, ¿se puede hacer ello? tendremos que convertirnos en adivinos. :D